# MYSQL select sum by months including with null values

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a mysql request that make the sum of values by months including those with null values.
The request result send only the first line without making the sum operation.

```
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(t1.sub_total,0)) AS amount, 
       am.a_month AS date
FROM (
        SELECT ifnull(vn.sub_total,0) as sub_total,
               cast(DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%M') as char) as mdate
        FROM orders_new vn
        WHERE order_status = 1
        AND order_date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31' 
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%M')
      ) t1 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN all_months am on t1.mdate = am.a_month
group by am.a_month
order by a_month_id asc;
```

result
[image]

below the source table
[image]

Comment: What is the output of this:  `SELECT MIN(order_date),MAX(order_date) FROM orders_new 
 WHERE order_status=1 AND order_date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31' ` ?   This query should product highest and lowest date in 2022, and I am thinking it only has dates in February.

Comment: the output i get is : 11 000 on februaty which is wrong. Normaly, i expect to get the sum of all entries by months in the range of date between 2022-01-01 and 2022-12-31. and for my example is : february = 11000+36000+500

Comment: Your sub-query is incompatible with [sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) , which is the default for some time now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `GROUP BY` clause in the subquery. Your query should be:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IFNULL(t1.sub_total, 0)) AS amount,
    am.a_month AS date
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         IFNULL(vn.sub_total, 0) AS sub_total,
         CAST(DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%M') AS char) AS mdate
     FROM 
         orders_new vn
     WHERE 
         order_status = 1
         AND order_date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31') t1 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    all_months am ON t1.mdate = am.a_month
GROUP BY 
    am.a_month
ORDER BY 
    a_month_id ASC;
```

Comment: @yas, Does this query work???

Comment: Yes for sure thanks for your help, have a nice day

Comment: You are always welcome...

Comment: @yas when somebody answers correctly your question you should upvote and mark as accepted, others can benefit from the answer as well

Comment: @Ergest Basha done thanks